# Execute Gradle task after subprojects are configured

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project Gradle build where subprojects are assigned version numbers independent of the root project. I'd like to inject this version number into a few resource files in each subproject. Normally, I'd do this by configuring the processResources task for each subproject in the root build. However, the problem is that Gradle appears to be executing the processResources task before loading the subprojects' build files and is injecting "unspecified" as the version.

Currently, my project looks like this:

**/settings.gradle**

```
include 'childA' // ... and many others
```

**/build.gradle**

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'com.example.exampleplugin'
}

subprojects {
    // This has to be configured before processResources
    customPlugin {
        baseDir = "../common"
    }

    processResources {
        // PROBLEM: version is "unspecified" here
        inputs.property "version", project.version

        // Inject the version:
        from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
            include 'res1.txt', 'res2.txt', 'res3.txt'
            expand 'version':project.version
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

**/childA/build.gradle**

```
version = "0.5.424"
```

I looked into adding [evaluationDependsOnChildren()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#evaluationDependsOnChildren()) at the beginning of root's `build.gradle`, but that causes an error because `childA/build.gradle` runs before `customPlugin { ... }`. I've tried using dependsOn, mustRunAfter, and other techniques, but none seem have the desired effect. (Perhaps I don't fully understand the lifecycle, but it seems like the root project is configured and executed before the subprojects. Shouldn't it configure root, then configure subprojects, and then execute?)

How can I get inject the version of each subproject into the appropriate resource files without a lot of copy/paste or boilerplate?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? One thing you can do is call project.subprojects { sub -> sub.evaluate()
//put code here after the subproject is evaluated } BUT I'm trying to do this without changing the evaluation logic so if you figured out another solution I'd love to hear it

Answer (score 10):

You could try using this method, with a hook:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated({
   // your code
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this figured out for myself. I'm using a init.gradle file to apply something to the rootProject, but I need data from a subproject.

First option was to evaluate each subproject before I modified it:

```
rootProject {
    project.subprojects { sub ->
        sub.evaluate()
        //Put your code here
```

But I wasn't sure what side effects forcing the sub project to evaluate would have so I did the following:

```
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
         //Put your code here
```

Comment: Can you try changing the order of these two as in `afterEvaluate { allprojects { ... } }` so that your code will wait once before starting the iteration instead of vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this:

```
subprojects { project ->
    // your code
}
```

Otherwise `project` will refer to your root project where no version has been specified.

Comment: Tried that, but gradle says 'project' doesn't have the properties, although I'm setting them in the subproject.